# React Router v4 - Dynamic Nested Paths

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, react-router

I'm trying to handle a route like this
`<Route path="/:first/:second?/:third?" />`
where the amount of optional params after "first" are unknown. What's the best practice for approaching this in React Router v4?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do something fancy with [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) which is what react router uses to resolve paths, but making a custom route that parses the location and reformats it to dynamic paths seems pretty easy!

```
let NoArityRoute = ({ component }) => (
  <Route
    children={({ location }) => {
      let params = location.pathname.split("/");
      let first = params[1];
      let rest = params.slice(2);
      let path = `/:${first}${rest.map(x => `/:${x}?`).join("")}`;
      return <Route path={path} component={component} />;
    }}
  />
);
```

Then wherever else:

```
<NoArityRoute
  component={({ match }) => (
    <div>params: {JSON.stringify(match.params)}</div>
  )}
/>
```

where `match.params` will be any number of dynamic args based on the url.